# Any way to set a default view in Word 2007 or 2010 and keep among restarts?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007

Every time I open a document in Word 2007 or Word 2010 on a wide-screen display I get the two-page view (which is actually very annoying for me). I would like to make Word display the one-page view, preferably with a specific zoom factor, by default and hence never display the two-page view. Is there a way to achieve that in 2007 or 2010 version?

Acceptable solutions include writing macros or using a 3rd party utility.

Comment: Hae you checked all your preference settings?

Comment: @martineau Indeed. Do you see in Word Options what I can't see?

Comment: Don't know if this applies to the versions of Word you're using, but the Help for the View menu in Word 2003 says "You can't set a default for all documents that you view in Word, because the view setting is stored with each individual document as a document property. You can save your document in the view with which you want it to open. Documents that you receive from others will open with the view in which they were previously saved."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A custom macro executed automatically upon opening a document is the right way. [This blog post](http://word.tips.net/Pages/T001343_Automatically_Opening_a_Document_at_a_Specific_Zoom_Setting.html) pointed me into the right direction. However, the code needed a slight modificaiton to make it work with both Word 2010 and Word 2007. Here it goes:

```
Public Sub AutoOpen()
    ThisDocument.Application.ActiveWindow.View.Zoom.PageColumns = 1
    ThisDocument.Application.ActiveWindow.View.Zoom.Percentage = 100
End Sub
```

Shall be installed into the `Normal.dotm` template.

Comment: How odd that you have to use a macro in your Normal template to override such an annoying "feature."

Comment: @Toby Only as odd as Microsoft usually is. Visual Studio *still* doesn't have a feature to trim trailing whitespace on save.

Comment: @jpmc26 That's an annoying one, too. No attention to detail is the norm, unfortunatelly.

Comment: Note that this will give a VBA error ("*Command only available in print layout view*") if you're not in Print Layout view. Either add a check against the active view type or automatically switch to Print Layout it on open by adding `ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdPrintView` before the other commands.

Answer (score 2):

Open the default template while in Word (path = C:\Users[your username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates. Open the file named either "Normal.dotm" or "Normal.dotx."  On the view tab, click "page layout" and in the zoom panel, click "one page." Save and close.  You can change a lot of other default settings here, too, such as font size, style, etc.

Comment: This is not a solution for 3rd party documents.

Answer (score 2):

In 2010: I opened a blank document, set it up to view the way I wanted, then did a Save As, and now Word is opening normally again. A simple Save didn't work had to Save As.

Apparently some document that a coworker had me work on (that she had started on) screwed up my default settings when I did a Save As.

Answer (score 1):

There's an option called "Open email attachments in Full-Screen Reading View" in the General tab.

[image]

Comment: Where specifically? I can see neither this option nor a 'General' tab. Currently I'm using Word 2007; however, I'm working with 2010 on other machines as well.

Comment: In the File, Options area, there's a General tab, and at the bottom of that is this setting.

Comment: Right, I can see it. In Word 2007 it's the Popular tab. However, this options won't influence the default view for non-attachments in either version of Word. However, thanks for trying.

Comment: Unselecting the "Open e-mail attachemnts in Full Screen Reading view" option disabled the "reading view" functions but had no impact on the 2 page view using Outlook 2007 and Word 2007 on a Windows 7 OS even after may attempts with saving and closing the application and even the Microsoft standard answer of rebooting didn't change the annoying 2 page view.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little more info: Word documents are saved with the view options and zoom factor to be used when they are opened again in Microsoft Word. It's strange that there is no way to override this behavior and set default values. Therefore I am fairly sure the only choice is to use a macro as suggested by Ondrej.

Answer (score 1):

Save As (instead of Save) will save with the new defined zoom setting in 2007. 
Save will keep the new defined zoom setting in 2013.

I do not have 2010 to compare.

Comment: A per-document behavior is not a solution. However, I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

While testing HTML software in MS Word 14, a collaborator opened a .docx that happened to be in 75% Zoom. The following day, my MSW14 App opened in 75% View, changing the original settings of the App.

I deleted Normal.dotm and reopened the App, and to my dismay, the condition still existed.

I then decided to type some characters into my MS Word 14, change the View to 100% and save the file. I closed MS Word then reopened the App.

Everything returned to normal (100% View).

I have just finished testing my results in my library using three different machines. My findings showed that this is a continually ongoing situation.

Simply stated in this case, if you want to change the default Zoom settings, try adhering to the 'Save As View yyy%' situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a shortcut to view "one page" to the quick access toolbar.  Just customize the quick access toolbar, find "one page", and click add.

Comment: Can you give a step-by-step process on how to do this?

Comment: Not sure about older versions, but in Word 2016 that option is called "Printed Page Layout," and you can find it in the list of available commands to add to the quick access toolbar.