# How to set Page Width as default in OneNote 2016?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-onenote, zoom

I want this button to be auto-clicked every time a page is loaded:

[image]

I find no option in the Display setting:

[image]

How can I do that? [Word can do that](https://superuser.com/q/237560/301042).

Comment: What version are you running? "We have fixed this issue in the latest Insider build with build number 16.0.6769.2011 or higher." Source: [OneNote 2016, build 16.0.6741.2017, page zoom issue - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-onenote/onenote-2016-build-16067412017-page-zoom-issue/7faffc76-2bdd-4871-a047-d10f8c5c1539)

Comment: File >Account > Update Options > Update Now.

Comment: My build is 16.0.9029.2106 (32 bit), and it says that I'm up to date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a bug only in Windows 7. A quick fix is to use AutoHotKey:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe ONENOTE.EXE
WinActivate WinWaitActive, ONENOTE.EXE
    sleep, 3000 
    Send !wi
~^PgUp::
~^PgDn::
~^n::
~^Tab::
~^+Tab::Send !wi
~^g::
    Input, key, V L1, {Enter}
    if (ErrorLevel == "EndKey:Enter")
        Send {Enter}!wi
return
```

If you are used to display it full-screen, you have to replace `!wi` with `{f11}!wi{f11}`. As of version 10325.20082, the bug seemed fixed, but it returns in version 18027.20181.

<sup>Related: [How to send an addition sequence after a series of input?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51165720/3416774)</sup>